# Devise User Authentication Required Unless Certain ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to make it so a Devise user has to be authenticated on the show action of a Rails controller unless show is a certain id. Is that possible? Is there something like the following?

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show id: 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out.

```
skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => :show, :if => lambda { 
    if params[:id]
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
      if @post.id == 1
    else
      false
    end
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => :show, :if => "Provide Condition"
```

Use the above syntax to skip authentication for specific cases, in your case ids.

Comment: Cool. How would I get the params[:id] in the if statement? I tried putting that in there but got an error.

Comment: params[:id] will be directly available in controller. Check the logs for the list of parameters being sent from browser

Comment: Can you tell me how it should be written? I've tried ":if => params[id: 1]", ":if => id: 58", and ":if => params[:id] == 1" but neither seem to be correct. I get "undefined local variable or method `params'"

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks.